# What controls the results of global search in Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning-experience, profile, global-search

FYI, this layout is in Service Console app. I want "Prescriptions" to appear at the top of the left column in search results for all users. When I'm under the System Admin profile this is what appears towards the top:

[image]

But when I log in a standard user, it looks like this:

[image]

I know it's not an object level or field level security, because when I got to "Show More" at the bottom left of the search column, this appears:

[image]